# reverse column order and delete lines

Tags: linux, shell, awk

assume I have the following hosts file ,

```
#hosts entry
No required line
#Start hosts lists

10.0.0.1 Server1
10.0.0.2   Server2
10.0.0.3   Server1
10.0.0.4  Server2
```

I want to delete this line and reverse order the colmun IP1  Servers etc
so the output in 2nd file will

```
 #hosts entry
#Start hosts lists

Server1 10.0.0.1
Server2  10.0.0.2
Server1  10.0.0.3
Server2   10.0.0.4
```

I used `awk '{print $2,$1}'`  but it will reverse everything and I want to just to start reverse from IP1 Server1 and move down , plus deleting the line.

Comment: Could you give some actual file contents, the literal strings `IP1`, `IP2` and `*another text` are hard to interpret on

Comment: question edited

Comment: It is not clear still, what is `No required line` here? What lines could it contain? It is important as we need to form a pattern to ignore such lines

Comment: its text only not numbers

Comment: is it a constant text or varying one? The idea is the parser needs to identify the nature of the string to add a ignore condition. How can be this done without knowing if its fixed or varying string. If varying what are the some examples

Comment: it will be : Hosts added by dev team - temp

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==2{next}                         # skip second line
       r {t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t}               # if r (reverse) flag is set, swap fields
       1;                                  # print line
       /^#Start hosts lists/{r=1}' file    # if the line matches set the r flag


#hosts entry
#Start hosts lists

Server1 10.0.0.1
Server2 10.0.0.2
Server1 10.0.0.3
Server2 10.0.0.4
```

Comment: Perfect , can you explain the answers please